# Fetching only one row even multiple exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an SQL query that will fetch only one row, even if multiple exist.

My DB looks like:

```
Name | Page | Date
John | 2201 | 22.05
John | 2202 | 22.05
John | 2202 | 23.05
```

What I want to have from select query is:

```
John | 2201 | 22.05
John | 2202 | 23.05
```

So if John visited same page multiple times, I want to store last time he visited that page.

I tried to do it with GROUP BY, but I think there should be another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this a problem with a `SELECT`, or with an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: In your example you have `SELECT DISTINCT`.
Imagine that your ouptut is a table (it is), then what you need to think about is: what is the _key_ for your output; if all columns are in the key then you can use `DISTINCT` but if not then you need to `GROUP BY` the key columns and then decide how to aggregate the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select name,page, max(date) as date
from MyTable
group by name,page
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it